# Can my notebook manage ubuntu as a host and kali as a guest and which virtual machine should i use?

Tags: vmware

I want to erase Windows and install Ubuntu as a host and Kali as a guest. And the question arises: Can my dell latitude 120l (intel m 1.73gh prossesor 2gb of ram 80gb hdd) handle this task and which virtual machine should I use (I'm using VMware 7 workstation under Win7 but it seems a little heavy)

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop probably can't handle virtualization, and if you're doing security auditing, the best choice is to install kali, for example on a flash drive, as opposed to in a virtual machine, so the tools can access the hardware directly.

Comment: That was really fast thank's a lot my friend.I'll go for a persistant installation on a 30 gb usb then.Thank you again for your time dear guntbert.